# How to apply a patch to a file in the root file system in yocto recipe

Tags: patch, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I want to apply a patch to a file in /etc in the rootfs. So I create a Yocto recipes

```
├── test_1.0.bb
└── files
    └── sshd.patch
```

and I've started to create the file .bb that is like this:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Patch files"
SECTION = "Patch"
LICENSE = "MIT"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI = " \
    file://sshd.patch \
"
```

- At this point I did not understand, what do I have to use the **do_install** or **do_patch** method?
- How do I have to specify the path to the file to be patched? (for example the file sshd to be patched is in /etc/ssh)

I tried different "configuration" with do_install(), but they didn't work. (When I do "bitbake core-image-base" there are not problems, but then in the rootfs the patch is not applied)

*English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to patch an existing recipe file, you need to create a `openssh_%.bbappend` file instead of `test_1.0.bb` and put every files to replace in `SRC_URI` (ie `file://sshd_config`) instead of `sshd.patch`.

Then, as those files already exist, you don't need to modify do_install from original recipe. Otherwise you need to add

```
do_install_append(){
    install -Dm 0644 ${S}/myfile ${D}${sysconfdir}/example/myfile 
}

# and modify FILES_${PN} if file is added in unusual place
```

By the way, a recipe cannot override another recipe file without being in conflict, so another solution is to patch it at rootfs creation, with [ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND). (That's why you cannot use `test_0.1.bb` for that).

Otherwise, patch files are automatically applied so you don't need to modify do_patch nor do_install.

If you add a recipe, don't forget to add it to image with `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " test"` in `local.conf` in your case.

Comment: So, I do not know if I understood wrong, but I tried to do this in my **test_1.0.bb** : `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "set_patches; "
set_patches () {
    patch  ${sysconfdir}/ssh/sshd_config_readonly ${WORKDIR}/sshd_config_readonly.patch
}` But it doesn't work.

Comment: you have to replace `${sysconfdir}/ssh` by `${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/ssh`. But ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND is an image variable, so you have to create a custom image from core-image-base to add it. Honestly, I think you should use bbappend for this kind of modification.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've used the "first option", so the ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND in a custom image (because I needed a custom image). In the near future, I'll try to use a .bbappend

Comment: Just another thing. I created the file openssh_%.bbappend, but can I use the file `sshd.conf.patch` (that I have created with `diff` command) in the `do_install_append () { ... }` or have I to use the file `sshd.conf` that I already patched ?

Comment: you have to use patched sshd.conf file

Comment: ok, thank you!. But what's happen if in the next version of sshd.conf there is a new pair of key value? Does my sshd.conf include this upgrade or not? I mean if in the next version of openssh, in the file sshd.conf there is a new string "foo bar", my openssh_%.bbappend will include both my patches and the string "foo bar" or not?

Comment: one way is to patch you file with sed like the following `do_install_append () {
    sed -i -e 's:#UsePAM no:UsePAM yes:' ${D}${sysconfdir}/ssh/sshd_config
}`